# Remove Multiples in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I was trying to do this exercise where I am supposed to build a prolog program that, when given a number and a list, returns a list without the multiples of the number. Now I have made this:

```
rm([],[]).  
rm(N, [Head|Tail], Result):-  
    Head mod N =:= 0,  
    rm(N, Tail, Result).  
rm(N, [Head|Tail], [Head|Result]):-  
    Head mod N =\= 0,  
    rm(N, Tail, Result).
```

It doesn't work and I don't really get why.
I hope someone can explain me why this doesn't work.
Thanks

Comment: "Doesn't work" gives us no indication of the problem, Please update your question to explain exactly what you mean, e.g. are you getting an error, is the code failing, is it giving an unexpected result etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:** the first clause has only two arguments.

You make recursive calls on `removeMultiples/3`: each time you call the same predicate `removeMultiples/3`. This way you enumerate over both lists. But eventually you will reach the end of the list.

The first clause however is about the `removeMultiples/2` predicate. So you need to **add a third argument**:

```
removeMultiples(_,[],[]).  % three arguments
removeMultiples(N, [Head|Tail], Result):-  
    Head mod N =:= 0,  
    removeMultiples(N, Tail, Result).  
removeMultiples(N, [Head|Tail], [Head|Result]):-  
    Head mod N =\= 0,  
    removeMultiples(N, Tail, Result).
```

Now it produces:

```
?- removeMultiples(3, [1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,15,3,1], Result).
Result = [1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 1] ;
false.
```

Comment: Oh wow... I was staring for hours just didn't get it haha. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

If you use SWI-Prolog, you can have a functionnal design :

```
:-use_module(library('lambda.pl')).

removeMultiples(N, In, Out) :-
    exclude(N+\X^(X mod N =:= 0), In, Out).
```